# Sort natural structure

Tags: string, matlab, structure, cell

I the following code:

```
files=dir('*.extension')
```

and I need to sort natural the 'files' struct, according to name, like `files(i).name`.

If i have file1, file2, file11, matlab order file1, file11,file2, and i want file1,file2,file11.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: If i have file1, file2, file11, matlab order file1, file11,file2.
Do you understand? sorry

Comment: Yes, you want it to be ordered by the numeric value of a sequence of  digits in the file name. Please add additional information like this in the question by editing it. The more concrete you explain your problem, the more likely you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply change your file names into file01, file02, file11. Then matlab will sort them the way you want. Or if you think it's so inconvenient to change file names one by one, you may have to write down some code:

```
for idx = 1:length(files)
    seq(idx) = num2str(files(idx).name(5:end);
end
[~,ord] = sort(seq);
for idx = 1:length(files)
    newfiles(idx)= files(ord(idx));
end
```